# textmate navigator view?

Tags: textmate

Is there a way to enable, or plugin a navigator like this:

https://github.com/Anomareh/Erebus.tmTheme/raw/master/screens/preview.png

I mean the little "code overview" besides the scroll bar?

Comment: I don't think there is, sorry.